# Where is my syntax error in this php program

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I am driving myself crazy trying to figure out where i am messing up. I've gone through this program 100s of times and I still can't figure out why it isn't running. All the areas in the database being called are not blank and all the variables are being brought correctly from the previous page.

```
$host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="sunbuggy";
    $database="mpg";
    $table="m";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die( "unable to connect to mysql server");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

        $driver=$_POST['driver'];
        $shuttle=$_POST['shuttle'];
        $gas=$_POST['gas'];
        $miles=$_POST['miles'];
        $cost=$_POST['cost'];

$getlastpri= "(SELECT * FROM '$table' ORDER BY `prikey` DESC)";


$sql=mysql_query($getlastpri);
$i=0;
$num=mysql_result($prime,$i,$prikey);
$shut=NULL;
while ($shut != $shuttle){
$shut=mysql_result($sql,$i,shuttle);
    $i++;}
if($shut == $shuttle)
    {$pastmiles=mysql_result($sql,$i,miles);}
else
    $pastmiles=Null;                        


if($pastmiles=Null):
    {$milestravled=Null;}
else:
$milestravled=$miles-$pastmiles;

$milespergallon=($milestravled/$gas);



$abc= "INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('','$driver','$shuttle','$gas','$miles','$cost', '$milestravled','$milespergallon')";
mysql_query($abc);

mysql_close();
echo "Your latest information has been input into the server";
?>`
```

Thanks so much in advance. Henry

Comment: What error messages are you getting? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

One error that I can see is your use of quotes around the table name here:

```
$getlastpri= "(SELECT * FROM '$table' ORDER BY `prikey` DESC)";
```

It should be:

```
$getlastpri= "SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY `prikey` DESC";
```

There may also be other errors though.

Your code is a complete mess, to put it nicely. You should build your application in small parts, writing only a few lines at a time and then testing that those few lines work as expected. An experienced programmer wouldn't write large chunks of code without testing any of it and then expect it to work on the first try.

Comment: You missed the comparison that is actually an assignment as others pointed out, but otherwise +1 to your last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see at a glance, this `if/else` is wrong:

```
if($pastmiles=Null):
{$milestravled=Null;}
else:
```

Should be

```
if($pastmiles == Null){
    $milestravled=Null
}
```

EDIT:

or as @Kolink pointed out in the comments, you can use this syntax:

```
<?
if($a):
    echo $a;
    if($b) {
      echo $b;
    }
else:
    echo $c;
endif;
?>
```

EDIT 2:

as @lserni pointed out, you're assigning NULL, not comparing it. You need to use `==` not `=`

Comment: `if: ... else: ...` is valid, but it needs an `endif;`.

Comment: if ($pastmiles=Null) works, but it's an assignment, not an IF.

Comment: To go a bit further into lserni's explanation; the truth value will take the value of the assignment. In this case it will allways be false.

Comment: @lserni - Thanks, edit#2 made. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) an error here:

```
if($pastmiles=Null):
    {$milestravled=Null;}
else:
    $milestravled=$miles-$pastmiles;
```

The body of the IF is an assignment, not a check. It will always set `$pastmiles` to NULL, even when it wasn't NULL to begin with.

You should have written:

```
if (NULL == $pastmiles)
    ...
```

The == makes it an equality check, and placing NULL first, will ensure that if you forget again a =, PHP will throw an error instead of going on like nothing happened.

Comment: Every way error probability to diminish must choose you. But that's actually a hint from Steve Maguire's "Writing Solid Code".